# extra column automatically appended in jtable (how to remove it )

Tags: java, swing, jtable, oracle11g

I am working on a java project
I am using jdk 1.6

I am want to add data from database in jtable 
I have achieved this by using DefaulTableModel 
and I got the column names by using ResultSetMetadata
but the problem is

**I am getting a extra column name A at the 0th index of jtable 
I want to remove this column 
it looks like this

A | deptno

I only need deptno
**

the code used for creating this model is

```
private void updateTable() throws Exception {

    String sqlrow = "Select count(*) from emp";
    rs= db.sta.executeQuery(sqlrow); 
        rs.next();                           
     int rows=rs.getInt(1);  
    System.out.println(""+rows);


    String sqldata = "SELECT deptno FROM emp";
   rs =db.sta.executeQuery(sqldata);
    rsMD = rs.getMetaData();
   numberOfColumns = rsMD.getColumnCount();
   ColumnNames = new String[numberOfColumns+1];
    System.out.println(""+numberOfColumns);

    for(int i=1;i<=numberOfColumns;i++)
    {
        String colName=rsMD.getColumnName(i);
        ColumnNames[i] = colName;
        System.out.println(""+ColumnNames[i]);
    }


    //Cj is a method which takes sqlQuery , rows, column
    Object[][] rowData=CJ(sqldata,rows,numberOfColumns);
    //jt is table name 
    jt.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(rowData,ColumnNames));

}
```

// code for cj()

```
     public Object[][] CJ(String sql,int rows,int cols)
{
    Object[][] obj=new Object[rows][cols+1];
    ResultSet rs=null;
    try{
         rs= db.sta.executeQuery(sql);
        int c=0;
            while(rs.next())
            {        
            for(int i=1;i<=cols;i++)
                {
                      obj[c][i]=rs.getString(i);                        
                }
                c++;
            }

        }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return obj;
}
```

I am using this code on 
button click

```
                 updateTable();
            jsp = new JScrollPane(jt); // jt is Jtable
             jp.add(jsp); //jp is jpanel
```

please help me out

Comment: Fix your shift key and apply it at the start of each sentence, every instance of the the word 'I', and as appropriate for J2SE classes and I might be able to read that question.

Comment: Is It okkz now I feel u understand now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not following the naming convention makes it hard to read, but I would suggest to take a closer look at the following piece of code

```
   numberOfColumns = rsMD.getColumnCount();
   ColumnNames = new String[numberOfColumns+1];
    System.out.println(""+numberOfColumns);

    for(int i=1;i<=numberOfColumns;i++)
    {
        String colName=rsMD.getColumnName(i);
        ColumnNames[i] = colName;
        System.out.println(""+ColumnNames[i]);
    }
```

Here you explicitly use more column names then `numberOfColumns`. Idem for your `CJ` method, where you start at index 1.
Just start all those `for` loops at index 0, make the arrays one shorter and everything should work

Comment: bro it cannot be done as in java the index starts from 1 if we will put 0 then invalid index error

Comment: +1 for spotting the problem (although the solution is off). When you access the "ColumnNames" array you need to use (i - 1), since array indexes are zero based. @C_J, learn standard Java naming conventions. Variable names do NOT start with an upper cased character.

Comment: I m beginner I am not use to the naming convention but i will see to it tht i don't make this kind of mistake

Comment: i achieved it but now the blank column appear's  on the black side of the JTable i.e deptno | B like this